# Netlogo: Calculate the diameter of a graph/network (with two foreach)

Tags: netlogo, graph-algorithm

As an answer for a question posted with this (almost) same title (Netlogo: Calculate the diameter of a graph/network), user C.Bradley afirms: "I have used two foreach loops to calculate the paths of one turtle to the rest". I would like to ask user C.Bradley how he has exactly done this. 
NB: I am sorry if this is not the right way to ask this question: I am an absolute beginner in Stackoverflow.com (I would have liked to contact directly C.Bradley, but I guess this is not possible in the platform, isn't it?) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how that person did it, but you can use the [NW extension](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html) for this:

```
max [ max [ nw:distance-to myself ] of other turtles ] of turtles
```

Comment: Dear Bryan, it works perfectly fine! Thank you very much!. M.

Comment: Great! Happy I could help! Make sure to mark the answer correct so others know this question has been answered.